# Cannot add Visual Effects to Grease Pencil Drawing (Blender 2.80 Beta)

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I used the newest version. Did I do something wrong?

[image: no]

Comment: What visual effects do you mean precisely?  What happens when you try?

Comment: @Kirbinator whatever I tried, nothing turned out. I have solved the problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Finally it has worked out. Change the view mode from *solid* to *LookDev* or *Rendered*.